# Definition of powers of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

For a given non zero complex number $z$ and a complex number $\alpha$, one defines
$$z^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha \log z} $$

But then, how does one define the powers of complex number when $z = 0$? I know that any branch of the complex logarithm is undefined for $z=0$

Comment: $ 0^{\alpha} = 0 $ for $ \alpha \neq 0 $.

Comment: 0^0 = 1. I think that was only defined very recently (Knuth in 1992 I think). Just bumped into a Quora on this.